# How do I architecture and implement custom membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, projects-and-solutions, membership-provider

I am trying to learn ASP.NET MVC. After reading through many articles on the web, I have put together a crude sample application that authenticates against an existing SQL database using custom membership provider.

My models class library project is structured as shown below.

- ***Sigma.Models***

  - **Implementations**

    - FormsAuthenticationService.cs
    - MembershipService.cs
  - **Interfaces**

    - IFormsAuthenticationService.cs
    - IMembershipRepository.cs
    - IMembershipService.cs
  - **Providers**

    - SigmaMembersipProvider.cs
  - **Repository**

    - SqlMembershipRepository.cs
  - MembershipModel.cs

My questions are as follows:

- Should I have to create another class library project like Sigma.DataAccess to keep the providers and repositories separately? Is this an acceptable way to do MVC solution architecture? This is only a proof of concept that I am working on and the actual project can get really huge. I want to make sure that I don't do anything stupid to begin with.
- IMembershipRepository and IMembershipService contain mostly the same functionalities except that IMembershipRepository returns data using the custom developed MembershipModel object; whereas IMembershipService is an interface of the standard ASP.NET MembershipProvider and returns MembershipUser and MembershipCollection. Should I have the interface IMembershipRepository inherit from IMembershipService?
- I would like to have models project reusable so I can use it against any other UI applications like WebForms or WinForms. Is that possible with the way project is structured?
- Also, I don't want to use the ASP.NET out-of-the-box membership provider because I need a solution that can work against an existing database. I assume that would mean I have to customize the features available in the ASP.NET membership provider to work against my custom database. Please correct me if my assumption is incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I have to create another class library project like Sigma.DataAccess to keep the providers and repositories separately? Is this an acceptable way to do MVC solution architecture? This is only a proof of concept that I am working on and the actual project can get really huge. I want to make sure that I don't do anything stupid to begin with.

Yes - keep them separate in case your implementation changes you have less impact.

> IMembershipRepository and IMembershipService contain mostly the same functionalities except that IMembershipRepository returns data using the custom developed MembershipModel object; whereas IMembershipService is an interface of the standard ASP.NET MembershipProvider and returns MembershipUser and MembershipCollection. Should I have the interface IMembershipRepository inherit from IMembershipService?

Actually in the samples provided - there actually seems to be no difference in the implementation - both methods are bool ValidateUser() which is definitely a repeat but because they each have an end use that could 'potentially' change they are abstracted into two separate interfaces, so I would not have one inherit from the other.

> I would like to have models project reusable so I can use it against any other UI applications like WebForms or WinForms. Is that possible with the way project is structured?

Yes - but I would break out and keep *only* the models in that project. Anything that is not a model - should not be in that project.

> Also, I don't want to use the ASP.NET out-of-the-box membership provider because I need a solution that can work against an existing database. I assume that would mean I have to customize the features available in the ASP.NET membership provider to work against my custom database. Please correct me if my assumption is incorrect.

That is correct - you need a custom SQL membership provider

Comment: I know it's slightly off topic, but this custom membership provider nonsense is exactly why I dropped ASP.NET MVC and picked up PHP using an MVC framework. Custom membership providers are needlessly over-complicated (and documentation is TERRIBLE). Not only that but it seems everyone who is using an existing database or doesn't want to use the bulky ASP.NET default has to go through this entire bloody effort just to afford authentication in their app. Seems nuts to me!

Comment: Mike that is a silly reason to drop a great framework. There are lots of code samples available to do just this..... Not to mention if you really want your own auth without a membership provider you can do everything in about ten lines of code for login support and adding roles. I think I will put a good MVC sample on my site for this thT I just started www.secure-coding.com.  I do agree it could be better but its really not too difficult.

Comment: Some people split out their interfaces... Some don't and each has their own reasons. If this project is to get large I would consider splitting projects out by purpose. one could also argue the security related interfaces though would fit right in with the security classes (membership) project though so it really is your call but try as a general rule to keep interfaces out of libraries that contain the concrete class implementations as it makes dependency injection cleaner and unit testing cleaner as well.